Random height node. Help needed!
I have this pattern of dots. A lot of them. Like 1000. Which I created as an svg. Imported. And converted to mesh.
I want to extrude each one randomly between values 1-5mm.
Are there any node / geometry artists here that can help and I can share the file so they can help to show me how they do it? I watched YouTube videos but couldn’t get it to work.

"This pattern of dots" - which pattern of dots? Why not use the Extrude Mesh node together with a Random Value with a Min value of 0.01 and a Max value of 0.05? I have no idea what your converted mesh looks like... are the dots separate vertices or do you have mesh circles now where the dots were in the SVG?

Hi Gordon. Thanks for your reply. Any chance you can contact me via Instagram so I can share some images. My handle is: @3xddd_

No, share your images in the question please for all to see here and having more chances to find a solution.
